# MySQL: Append the columns of multiple SELECT queries as a single output line

Tags: mysql

This is my example data in my table:

| id | date | time | label | i1 | i2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-25 | 11:53:00 | X | 0.111 | 60.0 |
| 2 | 2022-07-25 | 11:53:00 | Y | 0.222 | 70.0 |
| 3 | 2022-07-25 | 11:53:00 | Z | 0.333 | 80.0 |
| 4 | 2022-07-25 | 11:53:10 | Z | 1.999 | 100.0 |
| 5 | 2022-07-25 | 11:53:10 | X | 1.888 | 200.0 |
| 6 | 2022-07-25 | 11:53:10 | Y | 1.777 | 300.0 |

For every time sample data is written, there are three lines (for labels "X", "Y" and "Z"). They have the same date and time but everything else is different (id is unique primary key).

What I want is an output where I append (or combine?) my related lines (=same date & time) into a single row.

This should look like this:

| id | date | time | label | i1_x | i2_x | i1_y | i2_y | i1_z | i2_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-25 | 11:53:00 | XYZ | 0.111 | 60.0 | 0.222 | 70.0 | 0.333 | 80.0 |
| 4 | 2022-07-25 | 11:53:10 | XYZ | 1.888 | 200.0 | 1.777 | 300.0 | 1.999 | 100.0 |

It should be noted that X,Y,Z are not always in that order (like in the example here).

How would I manage to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an easy one
You need to group by `date` and `time` and then use `CASE` statements in order to produce your output:

```
SELECT 
   e.`id`
  ,e.`date`
  ,e.`time`
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.`label` SEPARATOR '')  AS label
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN e.`label`='X' THEN e.`i1` ELSE 0 END) AS i1_x
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN e.`label`='X' THEN e.`i2` ELSE 0 END) AS i2_x
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN e.`label`='Y' THEN e.`i1` ELSE 0 END) AS i1_y
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN e.`label`='Y' THEN e.`i2` ELSE 0 END) AS i2_y
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN e.`label`='Z' THEN e.`i1` ELSE 0 END) AS i1_z
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN e.`label`='Z' THEN e.`i2` ELSE 0 END) AS i2_z
FROM
  `example_data` e 
GROUP BY e.`date`,
  e.`time`
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your suggestion, I will try that.

But will this work with 1500+ columns as well or is there a limit for SQL queries?

Comment: Yes it will, I use similar query for extracting data from tables containing 30 million+ records. I added `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT` to produce just XYZ as label when extracting data from many rows

Comment: Ok, it DEFINITELY works as expected, so thank you for your solution. Now I will try to scale that up to my needs (and post here afterwards)